# Combining scopes inside IF statement in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I am trying to create a scope string for a search form. Can I build something like this with scopes:

```
scopestring = Product.all 
if params[:price].include? 
  scopestring = scopestring + '.free'
if params[:location].include? 
  # same for location 
end
```

Obviously I can't do that, but is there a way to do something similar. Any suggestions? Not a fan of 9 condition IF or case statements to handle various filters on the search page.

If I am going totally in a wrong direction here, what is the best way to handle long conditional statements in Rails? I would prefer staying away from gems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Product.all` isn't a scope, it actually does the search.  What you want is `Product.scoped`.  The scope returned is an object, not a string.  Assuming that `:free` is a scope:

```
products = Product.scoped
if params[:price] == "free"  #your example of include? doesn't make sense
  products = products.free
end
```

You can simplify it a bit more by refactoring into the model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :free, lambda {|free| free.nil? ? {} : where(:price => 0)}
end
```

and then in your controller:

```
@products = Product.free(params[:price])
```

Comment: The domain logic still doesn't make sense but you can get the structure from that example...

Comment: Product.scoped is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! (and sorry about not being clear with my question)